# Java, Android, Firebase Authentication signin out throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an app with email / password firebase authentication.

It starts with the login activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    ...
```

Then in my *onStart*, I check if the *currentuser* isn't null, then it navigates to my main activity. This part is working perfectly fine.

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (currentUser != null) {
        goMain();
    }
}
```

And here comes the problem, in the main activity I have a button where I call the signout function from LoginActivity.java:

```
public void logOut() {
    LoginActivity login = new LoginActivity();
    login.logMeOut();
}


public void logMeOut() {
    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if(user!=null) {
        mAuth.signOut();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Problem is when *logMeOut* runs, I get this beauty

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()' on a null object reference

I have tried to add `mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()` to the start of the *logMeOut* function, that still didn't solve my problem.

If I only call `mAuth.signOut()`, without the *FirebaseUser* part, I get the same error.

Comment: So, is all of the code you shared in the same class (`LoginActivity.java`)?

Comment: no, logOut, which calls the LogMeout is in the MainActivity.java

Comment: Okay, so do you have a `login()` method in the main activity also? If so, maybe you should reuse the `LoginActivity` object created there instead of creating a new instance for logout? It's difficult to answer this when you haven't shared a minimal yet complete and verifiable code example.

Comment: make an interface which is implemented by  loginactivity which contains logout function and try to call its method from main activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new Login activity in your logout method could that be an issue?

It seems to me the Auth objects would be re initialized right there. I do my logout the exact same way as you but it is within the main activity in a menu

```
 case R.id.sign_out_menu:
            mFirebaseAuth.signOut();
            Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);
```